# Cheapest license for external users to access custom objects

Tags: licenses, userlicense

Among the multitude of Salesforce licenses, which one is the cheapest for an external user to access <10 custom objects via the API?

I realize that actual prices differ for subscribers and I am not looking for exact figures. I just need the name of the license. Thanks!

Comment: Do you already have a community set? If you are looking only for 10 objects or less, then [Customer Community license](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) could possibly be a fit here.

Comment: @JayantDas I don't need Communities. The external users just need to stay in sync with SFDC through a couple of API calls.

Comment: My bad, I thought External Users as (External) Community Users. Have you seen the [Chatter Plus](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm&type=5), if that fits here? I am just not aware if it has API access or not.

Comment: @JayantDas Chatter Free already has API access so I believe Chatter Plus should have it too. The Chatter Plus license should fit but I don't know if it is the cheapest possible option. Do you?

Comment: I know that Chatter licenses are usually cheaper than other, so possibly it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the current name is Lighting Platform Starter and Starter Plus. Starter gives you access to 10 custom objects and Plus is around 100.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Comment: Do you know if the Lightning Platform Starter is cheaper than the Chatter licenses?